# How do I make my click catcher work?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm trying to create a simple click catcher where if you click `.image-class` the javascript will take the href from another element with a class name of `.btn` and send you to it's destination. Though I keep getting errors on lines 7 & 10 saying that undefined is not a function. How do I make this work?

```
<script>
var ClickCatcher=
{
    init:function(){
        var link = jQuery('.btn')[1].href;
        var imgCatch = jQuery('.image-class');
        imgCatch.addEventListener("click", ClickCatcher.clickListener, false);
    },
    clickListener:function(){
        window.location = link;
    }
};
ClickCatcher.init();
</script>
```

Comment: If your using jQuery already why not just use a simple click function?

Comment: I wanted to use as little jQuery as possible so I exercise my Javascript abilities. I'm a beginner in Javascript, and all I knew was you have to create a workaround for the `getElementsByClassName()` function for some versions of IE, which I did not want to do. Another goal was not to massage the HTML, so I had to use jQuery on that specific part. @Paul Radich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with jquery with a simple click event

```
jQuery('.image-class').on('click', function (){
    window.location = jQuery('.btn').eq(1).attr('href');
});
```

But if you still want to write in the way you have you can do:

```
var ClickCatcher = {
    init: function () {
        jQuery('.image-class').on('click', function (){
            window.location = jQuery('.btn').eq(1).attr('href');
        });
    }
};

ClickCatcher.init();
```

Just make sure to fire the init method after dom load.

update: One issue with it is that you have coded your target etc in the code rather then pass it, so its going to be hard to reuse, you'd be better off doing:

```
var ClickCatcher = {
    init: function ($button, loc) {
        $button.on('click', function (){
            window.location = loc;
        });
    }
};

ClickCatcher.init(jQuery('.image-class'), jQuery('.btn').eq(1).attr('href'));
```

That way the internal working is seperate from the dom (as you are passing the dom dependencies to the function.

Comment: Is there any you could correct my mistake first, then provide your more efficient solution? @atmd

Answer (score 1):

@atmd showed a very good way of doing this. If you just want to know what your mistake was though. It is wa an error in your jQuery stament to get the btn href

```
jQuery('.btn')[1].href
```

you need to call the attr function and then get the href attr. and use .eq(1) to reduce the set to the first btn

```
jQuery('.btn').eq(1).attr('href);
```

Comment: I appreciate that. if I could give you both the answer point, I would. So here's an up vote!